# how i can post to database contain these object a video and file and pdf with multer?

Tags: javascript, express, multer

**i have this database**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const FormCourse_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  FormCourse: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "cards",
    required: true,
  },
  date: { type: String },
  file: { type: String },
  video: { type: String },
  pdf: { type: String },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("FormCourse", FormCourse_schema);
```

**and this for posting for controller**

```js
exports.post_FormCourse = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // if (!req.userId) return res.status(406).json({ massege: "Unauthenticated" });

    const FormCourse_id = req.body.FormCourse_id;
    const isFormCourse = FormCourse.findById(FormCourse_id);
    if (isFormCourse.lenght < 1) res.status(202).json("FormCourse not found");
    const course = new FormCourse({
      date: req.body.date,
      file: req.file.path,
      video: req.file.path,
      pdf: req.file.path,
    });
    const result = await course.save();
    res.status(200).send({
      result: result,
      request: {
        type: "GET",
        url: "localhost:3002/form/" + result._id,
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "invalid id", error: err });
  }
};
```

**and this is the router what i define the post and here i suggest that the error show here**

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const FormCourses = require("../controllers/formCourses");
const checkAuth = require("../middleware/checkAuth");
const multer = require("multer");

const storageautre = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads/filesautre");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + file.originalname);
  },
});
const fileFilterautre = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === "application/*") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};
const uploadautre = multer({
  storage: storageautre,
  fileFilter: fileFilterautre,
});

////////
const storagevideo = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads/filesvideo");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + file.originalname);
  },
});
const fileFiltervideo = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === "application/video") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};
const uploadvideo = multer({
  storage: storagevideo,
  fileFilter: fileFiltervideo,
});
// \\\\\\\\
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./uploads/files");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === "application/pdf") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
/*-----------------------------get all orders-----------------------------*/
router.get("/", FormCourses.get_FormCourse);
/*-----------------------------post order -----------------------------*/
router.post(
  "/",
  uploadautre.single("file"),
  uploadvideo.single("video"),
  upload.single("pdf"),
  FormCourses.post_FormCourse
);
/*-----------------------------update order-----------------------------*/
router.patch("/:courseId", checkAuth, FormCourses.patch_FormCourse);
/*----------------------------delete order-----------------------------*/
router.delete("/:delete", checkAuth, FormCourses.delete_FormCourse);
module.exports = router;
```

**and lastly this app folder**

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");

require("dotenv").config();

//-----------------------------add routers paths-----------------------------//

const cardsRouter = require("./src/router/Cards");
const formRouter = require("./src/router/FormCourses");
const histoRouter = require("./src/router/Historiques");
const secondCardsRouter = require("./src/router/SecondCards");
const usersRouter = require("./src/router/Users");
//-----------------------------Connect with mongodb-----------------------------//

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT)
  .then(() => console.log("mongo connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

//-----------------------------middleware-----------------------------//
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET");
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
});
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//-----------------------------Routers---------------------------//

app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/card", cardsRouter);
app.use("/form", formRouter);
app.use("/histoRouter", histoRouter);
app.use("/secondCardsRouter", secondCardsRouter);

//-----------------------------Handling errors---------------------//

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Not found");
  res.status(404);
  next(error);
});
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500 | Error.status).json({
    message: error.message,
  });
});
module.exports = app;
```

**this show for 500 error testing with  postman**
*i think because of multiple fields of upload in router.post it throw to error so how it could be ?*

Comment: It's very hard to know what is the problem, which endpoint are you hitting, what is the payload? But even with that i would not be able to reproduce the code, because there are thing missing, for example: `src/router/Cards` can you create a git repository with running code that reproduces the problem, and explain how to cause it?

Comment: @Paulo Fernando src/router/Cards there are just old file but they don't have a probleme ,beacause i tested them , but anyway here is my github backend link( https://github.com/ghazali-web/backend  ) you should work on form file beacause the other there are right and  you should create file .env contains (DB_CONNECT=mongodb+srv://ghazali:2023@cluster0.6timxbv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
JWT_KEY=035f2d805f5f89a0f7b05b2026c337fd4346e4c9a2466b738c7a77b4a1a71a8f787a925aee11e50e072206a18cf66525b65980f787ce3f3315406e5b3740f2f3)

Comment: You want to save the files in the database? and the sum of the 3 files will probably be more than 16mb right? Because 16mb is the limit per document in mongodb, greater than that it's necessary to use: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/

Comment: @PauloFernando yes i want to save data in database and every file has it's own multer declaration ,of course the limits will be more than 16mb , but i use mongoose atlas that doesn't save neither images or PDF or video it just take references by id for object in db  and when i do get method he uploaded files from my laptop not from cloud,so if there a condition of size limit globaly (both on cloud and laptop) then there are no error ,else the error will be in router file because of multiple fields of multer ,this is what I'm guessing and thanks for you previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't fully understand your project, so I was not able to put the code in it.

But i think this can help you, it's a form that sends 3 files to mongo GridFS, you will get the  data of the uploaded files, id and extension for example. To download the file it's just pass the id for the /download.

for example: http://localhost:3008/download?id=639bd2fe44f218a5e0ea58d4

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
const { GridFsStorage } = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const multer = require('multer'); //use version 1.4.2

const connection = mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://ghazali:2023@cluster0.6timxbv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

const storage = new GridFsStorage({ db: connection });

const upload = multer({ storage });

let bucket;

connection.then(() => {
    bucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db);
})

const app = express()

app.post('/upload', upload.array('files'), async (req, res) => {

    res.send(req.files); //req.files gives you the id and the extension, you can save to download the file later
})

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    res.send(`
    <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="pdf_file">PDF: </label>
        <input id="pdf_file" type="file" accept="application/pdf" name="files">
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <label for="pdf_file">File: </label>
        <input id="pdf_file" type="file" name="files">
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <label for="pdf_file">Video: </label>
        <input id="pdf_file" type="file" accept="video/*" name="files">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
  `);
});

app.get("/download", (req, res) => {
    res.attachment("download"); //here you use the extension saved
    bucket.openDownloadStream(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.id)).pipe(res); //i am passing the id in the querystring, but you can pass other way
})


app.listen(3008, () => {
    console.log("Listening to 3008");
})
```

Comment: it give me an idea how i will work ,but mee too i can't pass gridfs like middleware or with other something so i will keep searching

Comment: You don't need to use it as middleware, you can call `upload` inside a normal post/get: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html#error-handling